# Terminal confusing

Tags: command-line, software-installation

How can I learn the terminal terms so I know what I'm doing instead of googling everything, in the sense where I can at least guide myself to do what I need to? An example is I want to use aircrack-ng but I have no clue what anything means to even navigate.

Comment: I've never heard of `aircrack-ng` so I googled it to answer your question. There are tons of tutorials on it you could have googled. Typically on this site you ask a question "how can I accomplish x". You're question then should be "How can I hack WiFi Passwords". Then maybe `aircrack-ng` steps will be posted in an answer or some other package altogether. That said hacking in this community is generally frowned upon and almost universally an unlawful activity but definitely hacking is universally immoral.

Comment: I do not want to learn that I already know that I said an example I jus used that off the top of my head not to learn that app I'm jus in a rush n wasn't thinking  I'd prefer not to be shamed or belittled I simply jus don't understand a lot of terminals terms no one wakes up knowing what a bunch of mixed up letters means and every post assumes people jus know these things

Comment: I find google can have most answers to questions from basic to advance.  Might have do different searches till you find the right terms to use.  One simple google search will gives pages of ubuntu commands, like this,  https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=ubuntu+commands&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

The following you may find helpful

https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/command-line-for-beginners#0

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CommandlineHowto

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Beginners/BashScripting

however. `aircrack-ng` is not a terminal command; it's an application run from terminal (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=aircrack-ng) and guides on using terminal will not tell what options are available for programs, though `man aircrack-ng` should display the reference-manual page for `aircrack-ng` (*providing the programmer created one*)